# How to restore html content in java?

Tags: java, android, html, mysql

I am saving some html code as text into mysql database.And I retrieve this text as a string using volley.When I save the html certain unwanted values get added to the html content. How do I remove this unwanted content and display the html content. I am using a webview to display this content and jsoup to parse it.
This is what I get after parsing the html content using  `Document doc = Jsoup.parse(instruction);`

```
 <html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      {&quot;result&quot;:[{&quot;instruction&quot;:&quot;\n\n\u00a0 \u00a0&lt;\/head&gt;\n\n\u00a0 \u00a0\n\n\u00a0 \u00a0 \u00a0 
      <ul>
         \n\n\u00a0 \u00a0 \u00a0 \u00a0 \u00a0
         <li>The Comprehensive R Archive Network&lt;\/li&gt;\n\n\u00a0 \u00a0 \u00a0 \u00a0 \u00a0</li>
         <li>
            A network of global web servers storing identical, up-to-date, versions of<br \="" />code and documentation for R&lt;\/li&gt;\n\n\u00a0 \u00a0 \u00a0 &lt;\/ul&gt;\n\n\u00a0 \u00a0 \u00a0 
            <p><br \="" /><strong>Download and Install R:&lt;\/strong&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;\n\n\u00a0 \u00a0 \u00a0 </strong></p>
            <ul>
               <strong>
                  \n\n\u00a0 \u00a0 \u00a0 \u00a0 \u00a0
                  <li>Use the CRAN mirror nearest to you to download R setup at a faster<br \="" />speed. Go to <a href="\&quot;url\&quot;">\u00a0http:\/\/cran.r-project.org&lt;\/a&gt;&lt;\/li&gt;\n\n\u00a0 \u00a0 \u00a0 \u00a0 \u00a0</a></li>
                  <li>
                     <a href="\&quot;url\&quot;">
                        Select one of the three download links according to your machine.&lt;\/li&gt;\n\n\u00a0 \u00a0 \u00a0 &lt;\/ul&gt;\n\n\u00a0 \u00a0 \u00a0 <img src="\&quot;file:\/\/\/storage\/emulated\/0\/rreadyreckoner_images\/download-r.png\&quot;" alt="\&quot;downloadr\&quot;" width="\&quot;191\&quot;" height="\&quot;129\&quot;" \="" />\u00a0\n\n\u00a0 \u00a0 \u00a0 
                        <ul>
                           \n\n\u00a0 \u00a0 \u00a0 \u00a0 \u00a0
                           <li>Run the R set up and follow the instructions of the installer.&lt;\/li&gt;\n\n\u00a0 \u00a0 \u00a0 &lt;\/ul&gt;\n\n\u00a0 \u00a0&lt;\/body&gt;\n\n&lt;\/html&gt;\n\n&quot;}]} </li>
                        </ul>
                     </a>
                  </li>
               </strong>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </body>
</html>
```

Is there a way by which I can retrieve the html content as a string and then refactor it into plain html and display it in a webview. I am new to programming so any help or suggestion is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @Jens Thank you for the edit can you help with a solution.

Comment: PS: You cannot have a UL inside an anchor

Answer (score 0):

You can use `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(text)` to escape unicode characters like `\u00a0` and `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(text)` to escape html-encoded characters like `&quot;`.

`StringEscapeUtils` class can be obtained from [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html).